# finding the average of the largest numbers input out of 3 by the user in c++

Tags: c++, average

So the design problem is:

Input 3 numbers and display the largest. Keep inputting sets of 3 numbers until the user wants to quit. Find the average of all of the largest numbers.

So entering the numbers works fine but when I try to plug in the `SENTINEL` value to stop the loop I need to type it in for all 3 numbers and it doesn't give me a correct average for the past numbers entered.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you for your time!

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int SENTINEL = -1;
    int num1;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    int largest;
    int sum;
    int count;
    float average;

    // initialize the count and sum
    count = 0;
    sum = 0;

    while (num1 != SENTINEL)
    {

        // Prompt user for the first number or to quit
        cout << "If you want to quit enter " << SENTINEL << " to stop\n " << endl;
        cout << "Enter first number  ";
        cin >> num1;

        // Prompt the user for the second number
        cout << "please enter second number                  ";
        cin >> num2;

        // Prompt the user for a third number
        cout << "please enter the third number               ";
        cin >> num3;

        // Compare numbers 1 and 2 for the largest number
        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            largest = num1;
        }
        else
        {
            largest = num2;
        }

        // Compare largest to last number input
        if (num3 > largest)
        {
            largest = num3;
        }

        // Display the largest number
        cout << "largest number is: " << largest << endl;

        // Increment the count
        count++;

    }



    if (count > 0)
    {
        average = sum / count;
        cout << "Average of the numbers is " << average;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't initialize `num1` before you use it, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You also don't increase the sum.

Comment: I will change it to initialize num1 thanks I realize I haven't added to increase the sum yet but the code is not complete the problem I am doing it in pieces and testing it and was stuck at this part..

Answer (score 1):

Using a `break;` instruction is a possibility, but often considered unelegant and hard to maintain.

The reason is that you break the flow of the code, and the reader of your program (that may not be you in big programs or if you share it) expect the code of your loop to be continued to the end of it. If your function has one or several `break;`instructions, it may be hard to understand the intent of the function, because you have to remember in which cases the loop will have already ended.

The basic principle to solve your problem is to start your loop at the right place, just after getting a value for num1. Then your loop also has to end with it. That way, you will always check your exit condition right after the user keyed in num1.

```
// initialize the count and sum
count = 0;
sum = 0;

// Prompt user for the first number or to quit
cout << "If you want to quit enter " << SENTINEL << " to stop\n " << endl;
cout << "Enter first number  ";
cin >> num1;

while (num1 != SENTINEL)
{

    // Prompt the user for the second number
    cout << "please enter second number                  ";
    cin >> num2;

    // Prompt the user for a third number
    cout << "please enter the third number               ";
    cin >> num3;

    // Compare numbers 1 and 2 for the largest number
    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        largest = num1;
    }
    else
    {
        largest = num2;
    }

    // Compare largest to last number input
    if (num3 > largest)
    {
        largest = num3;
    }

    // Display the largest number
    cout << "largest number is: " << largest << endl;

    // Increment the count
    count++;

    // Prompt user for the first number or to quit
    cout << "If you want to quit enter " << SENTINEL << " to stop\n " << endl;
    cout << "Enter first number  ";
    cin >> num1;
}

if (count > 0)
{
    average = sum / count;
    cout << "Average of the numbers is " << average;
}

return 0;
```

Note: I did not solve the code mistakes here, as mentioned in the comments (variables not being declared, the sum not being updated, etc.).

Comment: 1. You're replicating code (those 3 lines that appear before the loop and at the end of each iteration), which is even less elegant than a `break` (what's not elegant about a `break` anyway?). 2. You forgot one small thing required for this program to actually work (hint: `sum` has something to do with it).

Comment: Replicating code is indeed not elegant either, but I would not say less than `break`. The problem with the break instruction is that it breaks the flow of the code. In one small program, it may not be very important, but you expect a loop to be continued from the start to the end. Having to look for other possible termination of the loop makes the code harder to read, and is forbidden or really not appreciated in a lot of companies.

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally break your loop immediately after input of num1.

```
cin >> num1;
if (SENTINEL == num1)
{
  break;
}
```

Comment: I can't use a break unless its a switch statement per the instructor I tried it lol

Comment: Then use `continue;` instead :) it jumps to the next iteration which then checks the SENTINEL

Answer (score 0):

After

```
cin >> num1;
```

You can check, if its SENTIEL number and break from the loop:

```
if (num1 == SENTIEL)
    break
```

so that it will not execute another cin's.